# How to lerp camera rotation from current direction towards another?

Tags: aframe

I'm using A-Frame and I'd like to know if there's a component or a way to smoothly rotate from current direction towards another over a few secs. I plan to use this with the [alongpath component](https://github.com/protyze/aframe-alongpath-component) just **before** playing the movement on my camera. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Code, what it means to rotate from a direction to another?

Comment: Sure. I forgot most important part sorry: I have a camera attached to an entity, and I'd like it to rotate from current direction towards another specific point, but not abruptly. Smoothly rotate from one direction to another.

Comment: I think the lookAt vector is what I'm missing, but I'm not well-versed with graphics to just set values to it. I want the camera simply to look at another direction.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/haydenjameslee/aframe-lerp-component

Comment: I found out that <a-animation> could do this in a much simpler way, though this component looks interesting.